# A loop won't stop

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I am trying to make an RPG for a school project. The game ends when you defeat the boss.You can train and fight random monsters before challenging the boss. The problem i am having right now is that the loop in the fight method will not stop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class A{
public static void main(String []args){
    Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rng = new Random();

    int day = 0;
    int choice;
    String playerName;

    int playerHealth = 10; int playerAttack = 5; int playerDefense = 5;
    int boss1Health = 1000; int boss1Attack = 900; int boss1Defense = 900;
    int slimeHealth = 100; int slimeAttack = 20; int slimeDefense = 20;
    int goblinHealth = 80; int goblinAttack = 40; int goblinDefense = 10;

    System.out.print("What is your name? ");
    playerName = get.next();
    System.out.println("...Welcome, " + playerName);

    while(bothAreAlive(playerHealth, boss1Health)){
        ++day;
        while(true){
            action(day);
            choice = get.nextInt();
            if(choice == 1){
                fight(playerName, playerHealth, playerAttack, playerDefense, "Skeleton King", boss1Health, boss1Attack, boss1Defense);
                break;
            }
            if(choice == 2){
                int encounter = rng.nextInt(2);
                if(encounter == 0){
                    slimeHealth = 100;
                    fight(playerName, playerHealth, playerAttack, playerDefense, "Slime", slimeHealth, slimeAttack, slimeDefense);
                }
                else if(encounter == 1){
                    goblinHealth = 80;
                    fight(playerName, playerHealth, playerAttack, playerDefense, "Goblin", goblinHealth, goblinAttack, goblinDefense);
                }
                break;
            }
            if(choice == 3){
                playerHealth += 10;
                playerAttack += 5;
                playerDefense += 5;
                break;
            }
            if(choice == 4){
                showStats(playerName, playerHealth, playerAttack, playerDefense);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static int attack(String attacker, String defender, int aAttack, int dDefense, int dHealth){
    int damage = Math.max(0, aAttack - dDefense);
    System.out.println("\n" + attacker + " did " + damage + " damage to " + defender + ".");
    dHealth = dHealth - damage;
    System.out.println("\n" + defender + "'s health is now " + dHealth);
    return dHealth;
}

public static int fight(String playerName, int playerHealth, int playerAttack, int playerDefense, String enemyName, int enemyHealth, int enemyAttack, int enemyDefense){
    Random rng = new Random();
    while(bothAreAlive(playerHealth, enemyHealth)){
        int playerChance = rng.nextInt(5);
        int enemyChance = rng.nextInt(5);
        if(enemyChance > 1){
            attack(enemyName, playerName, enemyAttack, playerDefense, playerHealth);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("\n" + enemyName + " missed!");
        }
        if(playerChance > 1){
            attack(playerName, enemyName, playerAttack, enemyDefense, enemyHealth);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("\n" + playerName + " missed!");
        }
    }
    if(enemyHealth >= 0){
        System.out.println(enemyName + " has won...");
    }
    else if(playerHealth >= 0){
        System.out.println("You have won!");
    }
    return enemyHealth;
}

private static boolean bothAreAlive(int yourHealth, int enemyHealth){
    return yourHealth > 0 && enemyHealth > 0;
}

public static void action(int day){
    System.out.println("Day: " + day);
    System.out.println("\nWhat will you do today?\n(1)Fight boss\n(2)Fight random monster\n(3)Train\n(4)Show stats");
}

public static void showStats(String playerName, int health, int attack, int defense){
    System.out.println("Name: " + playerName);
    System.out.println("Health: " + health);
    System.out.println("Attack: " + attack);
    System.out.println("Defense: " + defense);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am reading is wrongly but it seems that the attack method isn't really decreasing the health level.

Answer (score 0):

```
  while(bothAreAlive(playerHealth, enemyHealth)){
        int playerChance = rng.nextInt(5);
        int enemyChance = rng.nextInt(5);
        if(enemyChance > 1){
            attack(enemyName, playerName, enemyAttack, playerDefense, playerHealth);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("\n" + enemyName + " missed!");
        }
        if(playerChance > 1){
            attack(playerName, enemyName, playerAttack, enemyDefense, enemyHealth);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("\n" + playerName + " missed!");
        }
    }
```

In Java you cannot pass an `int` to a method, assign to it a new value in the method and see the variable passed to the method with the change.
So `playerHealth` and `enemyHealth` are never updated in the `fight()` method.

The `attack()` method you call in the `fight()` method :

```
public static int attack(String attacker, String defender, int aAttack, int dDefense, int dHealth){
```

returns the left health of the attacked person : player or enemy. 
So you could assign the returned value to playerHealth or enemyHealth according to who is attacked.
For example :

```
  while(bothAreAlive(playerHealth, enemyHealth)){
        int playerChance = rng.nextInt(5);
        int enemyChance = rng.nextInt(5);
        if(enemyChance > 1){
            playerHealth = attack(enemyName, playerName, enemyAttack, playerDefense, playerHealth);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("\n" + enemyName + " missed!");
        }
        if(playerChance > 1){
            enemyHealth = attack(playerName, enemyName, playerAttack, enemyDefense, enemyHealth);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("\n" + playerName + " missed!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Well, the exact problem here is, as you mentioned, the while loop inside fight method runs indefinitely.

**What causes this problem?**

Condition inside your while loop is always true as `playerHealth`, `enemyHealth` values remain unchanged.

```
while(bothAreAlive(playerHealth, enemyHealth))
```

In case if you thought that, passing `playerHealth` and `enemyHealth` as a parameter to attack method will change their value, that is wrong. Java is strictly pass-by-value and since `int` is a primitive type, it's local to a method (A copied value is passed to the method).

**Solution**

Note that, your attack method returns the new health `dHealth` and no where you are using it.
Simply assign the returned value to `playerHealth` and `enemyHealth` appropriately, and that would do the trick.

```
playerHealth = attack(enemyName, playerName, enemyAttack, playerDefense, playerHealth);
```

and

```
enemyHealth = attack(playerName, enemyName, playerAttack, enemyDefense, enemyHealth);
```